# uploading a uri or should it be converted?

Tags: node.js, react-native, amazon-s3

I am sending image data from my react native application to my node js backend which i want to upload to S3 . I want to know exactly which format i must change the data to in order to upload it to my S3 . Below is the formdata which i am logging in my backend at the moment .

```
[
  'file',
  {
    uri: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CA974BC6-6943-4135-89DE-235BC593A54F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540lb2020%252Fmy/ImagePicker/D7119C77-60D0-46CC-A194-4F1FDE0D9A3D.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'hi.jpg'
  }
]
```

My backend has this code below also . Would making the above code equal file work ? if not , suggestions will be appreciated .

```
const params = {
    Bucket:"myarrowbucket", // bucket you want to upload to
    Key: "filename"+".png",
    Body: file,
    ContentType:'image/png',
    ACL: "public-read",
  };
```

I have tried uploading and the image doesnt open correctly on S3 or gives me Error: Unsupported body payload object

**Updated code - - no path found error**

```
app.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
const uri = (req.body._parts[0][1].uri)
const file = uri.substring(7);
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);  
  const params = {
      Bucket:"myarrowbucket", // bucket you want to upload to
      Key: "filename"+".png",
      Body: fileStream,
      ContentType:'image/png',
      ACL: "public-read",
    };
  const data = await client.upload(params).promise();
    return data.Location; // returns the url location
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried uploading and the image doesnt open correctly on S3 or gives me > Error: Unsupported body payload object

You need to provide a stream to the S3 client.

```
app.post("/upload", fileUpload(), async (req, res) => {
  const uri = (req.body._parts[0][1].uri)
  const file = uri.substring(7);
  const params = {
      Bucket:"myarrowbucket", // bucket you want to upload to
      Key: "filename"+".png",
      Body: Buffer.from(req.files[0].data, 'binary'), <-- PROVIDE DATA FROM FORM-DATA
      ACL: "public-read",
    };
  const data = await client.upload(params).promise();
  return data.Location; // returns the url location
});
```

You can use a library like [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) to handle the form data conversion.

Comment: I get an error message saying [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\var\mobile\Containers\Data\Application\CA974BC6-6943-4135-89DE-235BC593A54F\Library\Caches\ExponentExperienceData\%2540lb2020%252Fmy\ImagePicker\145092D1-E72D-4FD9-A152-4C90A42A1C66.jpg'] {

Comment: That means the path you provided is incorrect

Comment: i am using image picker on react native -> sends form data to nodejs with uri ->removes begging file:// from uri and passes output into fs.createreadstream().

Comment: Are handling the multipart/form-data stream in NodeJS before passing the output to the S3 client?

Comment: yes , i will update the code to show @Brian

Comment: Edited my answer now based on your new code.

Comment: Body: Buffer.from(req.files[0].data, 'binary'),

Comment: what data are we trying to access in req.files[0] as it gives me undefined?

Comment: You'll need to change that part. req.files will include the actual binary data of the image you're uploading. You can look at the link I added to understand it better. Essentially you will provide binary data to S3 client to upload the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250655/discussion-between-lb2020-and-brian).